# Understand python syntax reduce lambda

Tags: python

I have a pandas series 'structures'. It contains rows of list of characters.

```
structures[0] = ['C', 'H', '[', '#']`
```

The line below is basically trying to find the union of all characters present in all the rows

```
charset = list(reduce(lambda x, y: set(y) | x, structures, set()))
```

But, I'm not able to understand the syntax. What is | doing and why is set() being passed as an argument to reduce?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `reduce` or `lambda`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.

Comment: @melpomene It looks like that the OP understands none of `reduce`, `lambda`, `|`. Too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set(y) | x` is the union of `set(y)` and `x`.

The `set()` at the end is the initial value for `reduce()`, the first value of `x` that will be used so that the function can get going. The first value in `structures` will be the first value of `y`.

If you left out the initial value, i.e. something like:

```
charset = list(reduce(lambda x, y: set(y) | set(x), structures))
```

then if `structures` is empty this will raise:

```
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

and if `structures` has length one then `reduce` will just return the one element, not converted to a set.

In general `|` is the bitwise OR operator but sets override several operators for their own meaning. For future reference the character is called a pipe, so for example searching for "python set pipe" yields some answers.